# How to extract and sum distinct values in from a column and create a column with the sum

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a column which is the sum of the unique values of column SIZE

```
TYPE    SIZE
A   24522145.17
A   35359867.65
A   35359867.65
A   35359867.65
A   35359867.65
A   35359867.65
A   24522145.17
A   35359867.65
A   35359867.65
A   8527174.786
```

I don't want the count of unique values but the sum, that from the data above the sum will be adding (24522145.17 + 35359867.65 + 8527174.786). This after grouping by variable TYPE.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We group by 'TYPE', get the `unique` 'SIZE' and return with the `sum` of those values in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(TYPE) %>%
     summarise(Sum = sum(unique(SIZE), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  TYPE        Sum
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 A     68409188.
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(TYPE = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A"), SIZE = c(24522145.17, 35359867.65, 35359867.65, 35359867.65, 
35359867.65, 35359867.65, 24522145.17, 35359867.65, 35359867.65, 
8527174.786)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but is it possible to create a column and add it to the existing dataset even though the number of rows would not match? I tried mutate with your code and it didn't work.

Comment: @DSan Just change itt o `mutate` i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(TYPE) %>%
     mutate(Sum = sum(unique(SIZE), na.rm = TRUE))`. It wouldn't matter about number of rows, as `sum` is just a single number and it gets recycled to the length of each group

Answer (score 2):

We could also get the distinct combos and add those using `count` where the `wt` are the values we want to sum.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  distinct(TYPE, SIZE) %>%
  count(TYPE, wt = SIZE)  # shortcut for group_by(TYPE) %>% summarize(n = sum(SIZE))
```

data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              TYPE = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
              SIZE = c(24522145.17,35359867.65,
                       35359867.65,35359867.65,35359867.65,35359867.65,
                       24522145.17,35359867.65,35359867.65,8527174.786)
)
```

Comment: I like this approach! Could you explain `wt`! Upvote+!

Comment: As per the documentation, `count()` computes `sum(wt)` for each group.

Answer (score 1):

With your properly formatted data

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~TYPE, ~SIZE,
  "A",   24522145.17,
  "A",   35359867.65,
  "A",   35359867.65,
  "A",   35359867.65,
  "A",   35359867.65,
  "A",   35359867.65,
  "A",   24522145.17,
  "A",   35359867.65,
  "A",   35359867.65,
  "A",   8527174.786
) -> df
```

you could do (h/t @akrun)

```
aggregate(SIZE ~ TYPE, unique(df), sum)
```

returning

```
  TYPE     SIZE
1    A 68409188
```

Comment: The result, per the question, should be `(24522145.17 + 35359867.65 + 8527174.786) ~ 68409188`.

Comment: Right, and `sum` rather than `mean`. Corrected, thanks @akrun!

Comment: @ktiu sorry, I meant that only, but may be got distracted. thanks

Answer (score 1):

We could use `filter` and `!duplicated()`:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(TYPE) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(SIZE)) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(SIZE))
```

Output:

```
  TYPE        sum
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 A     68409188.
```